# Layer 2 (VMAC) Network Redundancy Options for Linux

Tags: linux, networking

With heartbeat and keepalived, the redundancy options I have always used work by moving a virtual IP address to a new machine (A layer 3 solution). The new machine sends out a gratuitous arp to tell machines on the network its MAC address is the new MAC for that IP.

Are there any current network redundancy options that use a virtual MAC address (layer 2) that gets moved between machines as well as the virtual IP? This would be useful for certain operating systems that don't understand GARP requests. I did find [this keepalivd thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.keepalived.devel/1524) (from a Server Fault user it so happens) but it is back from 2005. Does anyone know the current state of virtual mac failover in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VRRP ([RFC2338](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2338.txt) for VRRPv2, [RFC5798](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5798.txt) for VRRPv3 which added IPv6 support) uses a virtual MAC address for each instance's virtual router, but still sends gratuitous ARP on a switchover.

While the keepalived VRRP implementation ignores this part of the specification and simply uses the interface MAC, VRRPd is capable of using the virtual MAC.

However, the concept of a virtual MAC doesn't play well with the Linux concept of a network interface; the VRRPd process must change the interface's MAC address to the virtual MAC when it takes over, which prevents running multiple VRRP virtual routers on a given interface.

Comment: Since this answer was written the Linux kernel has gained support for multiple MAC addresses per physical interface using macvlan virtual interfaces. Keepalived now features a "use_vmac" option that  implements what is being required here.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly HP's various 'VirtualConnect' products allow you to use a preconfigured MAC or range of MACs that you then map to a specific server as required. I've used this extensively and it works a treat, although we use it to pre-define new server's ethernet and FC environment before the physical server arrives on site but it could be used in the manner you describe.

This is entirely OS-gnostic btw, it's a virtual hardware thing, I'm not aware of a Linux-specific way of doing this other than via some form of scripting.

Comment: I think Kyle really want this automatically to happen as part of a cluster fail-over and resource ownership change and what you're proposing is basically a deployment thing that you would use after parts replacement or machine change etc.

Comment: If can be easily scripted though.

Comment: How do you trigger the script and who triggers it? I do understand that what you propose is technically doable but it would certainly be some kind of weakest link in your cluster.

Answer (score 2):

[CARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Address_Redundancy_Protocol) uses a virtual MAC addreses (in a manner similar to [VRRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRRP), but not patent-encumbered) for each IP redundancy group. The master host in the group responds with the virtual MAC. When failover occurs the MAC doesn't change. I've used [ucarp](http://www.ucarp.org/project/ucarp) on Linux and been very pleased with it.

Edit:

This isn't going to help you (everybody, downvote away!). The Linux CARP implementation I linked to, ucarp, doesn't actually use a virtual MAC address. The original OpenBSD implementation does, but the Linux implementation does not. Everything worked as I wanted in my deployment so I never dug down into it (until this morning) to see that it isn't doing anything useful at layer 2 for Kyle's needs.

I am seeing some discussion on the [Linux HA list](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linuxha/users/69198) about using `ifconfig` to assign virtual MAC addresses to interfaces at failover-time. That doesn't sound like a tremendously bad option, especially if you're using virtual hardware and can afford to "spend" a virtual NIC on it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the current state of things, but they used to use FreeBSD + CARP + HAProxy; but no longer do. They should be aware of CARP already.

Comment: This is Linux, so I think it would be UCARP in this case, not sure if UCARP support VMAC -- looking into it now.

Comment: @KyleBrandt: That'd be a "no".  >sigh<